# Excel how to find out the keyword in the sentence

Tags: excel

I want to find out whether the sentence has the word I want, for instance, I want to know whether "apple" is in "I have an apple".

Below is the code,
 
Sub test()

```
LastRow_Sheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
LastRow_Sheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count

For x = 2 To LastRow_Sheet1

    po_number = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 7).Value
    site_name = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 1).Value

    For y = 2 To LastRow_Sheet2
        If po_number <> Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, 1).Value Then
        With Worksheets("Sheet2") 
            If InStr(1, CStr(site_name), .Cells(y, 30)) >= 1 Then
                .Range(.Cells(y, 1), .Cells(y, 31)).Copy
                nextRow = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(Sheets("Sheet3").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & nextRow).PasteSpecial
            End If
          End With
        End If
    Next
Next
```

End Sub

And for some reason, `If InStr(1, CStr(site_name), .Cells(y, 30)) >= 1 Then` is not working .., and I am sure that the type of `Cells(y, 30)` is string, Could anyone tell me what happen ?

Many thanks!!

Jimmy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the order of the parameters:

```
If InStr(1, .Cells(y, 30), CStr(site_name)) >= 1 Then
```

Comment: Lookup the description of the function. If you search for a string in another string you always give two parameters: the haystack and the nail (the one you are searching for and the one in you are searching). You won't find the string 'I have an apple' inside the string 'apple', it does not fit into it.